# Calculating growth of individual recaptures in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate growth for individuals from a large capture/mark/recapture dataset. I have data for every marked individual, but not all of them were recaptured. Basically, I capture and mark individuals of a certain size. A certain time later, I capture and mark individuals of a larger size. Some of these are already marked recaptures, while others are new individuals.

What I would like to do is take this data set, then calcualte growth for the recaptured individuals. At it's base, this is fairly simple. A recaptured individual will have the same tag number each time. So, I simply have to subtract the total length (TL) when the individual was first marked from the TL at recapture. However, I do not know how to tell R to select a previous row based on a certain column, then apply a function to it. The tricky part to me is that the values I am trying to match are in the same column. I have looked at ?%in% and tried to see if plyr has anything that would work, but could not find anything.

EDIT: longer data frame to handle multiple (more than 2) recaptures of the same individual. In that case, the growth from the original capture should be calculated.

I created a sample data frame using the following:

```
tlran=c(rnorm(5,mean=50,sd=5),rnorm(5,mean=200,sd=5), rnorm(5,mean=400,sd=10))
TaggingData=as.data.frame(trunc(tlran,0))
names(TaggingData)="TL"
TaggingData$Tag=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,7,3,4,8,1,9,10,3)
TaggingData$Date=c("01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2017","01.01.2017","01.01.2017","01.01.2017","01.01.2017")
```

So my sample data looks like this:

```
>TaggingData    
TL    Tag       Date
1   36   1 01.01.2015
2   44   2 01.01.2015
3   51   3 01.01.2015
4   49   4 01.01.2015
5   50   5 01.01.2015
6  203   6 01.01.2016
7  198   1 01.01.2016
8  203   7 01.01.2016
9  193   3 01.01.2016
10 210   4 01.01.2016
11 403   8 01.01.2017
12 402   1 01.01.2017
13 393   9 01.01.2017
14 391  10 01.01.2017
15 415   3 01.01.2017
```

EDIT: Manually, what I would like my data to look like:

```
>TaggingData    
TL    Tag       Date    Growth
1   36   1 01.01.2015   NA
2   44   2 01.01.2015   NA
3   51   3 01.01.2015   NA
4   49   4 01.01.2015   NA
5   50   5 01.01.2015   NA
6  203   6 01.01.2016   NA
7  198   1 01.01.2016   162
8  203   7 01.01.2016   NA
9  193   3 01.01.2016   142
10 210   4 01.01.2016   161 
11 403   8 01.01.2017   NA
12 402   1 01.01.2017   366
13 393   9 01.01.2017   NA
14 391  10 01.01.2017   NA
15 415   3 01.01.2017   364
```

Basically, I want R to realize that because the tag number in row 7 is identical to the one in row 1, TL for row 7 should be subtracted from TL in row 1 and ideally written in a new column, for example TaggingData$Growth.

I am unfortunately completely lost here. I can select duplicate tag numbers using duplicates(TaggingData$Tag), but I feel this does not help me.

Can anyone suggest a package/functions to look at, or even help me out with some code?

EDIT: I have tried the suggested aggregate, and also package data.table with the following code:

```
Recap=data.table(TaggingData)
setkey(Recap,Tag)
Recap[,diff:=c(NA,diff(TL)),by=Tag]
```

While this gives me the numbers I am looking for, the formatting is not at all what I was hoping for and would require quite a bit of work to clean it up to what I need to continue working with the data.

Comment: Can you make your example a bit bigger? What happens when 1 appears for the third time? You substract from line 7 to 197?.

Comment: @Roman, that is actually something I was wondering about as well. It seems I can get something working with data.table, but while it does calculate growth rates for me, it does not put out the formatting I was hoping for. I will edit my original question and expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your result it seems that you want the `cumsum` of the `diff`. To follow your `data.table` approach, then

```
library(data.table)
Recap=data.table(TaggingData)
setkey(Recap,Tag)
Recap[,diff:=c(NA,cumsum(diff(TL))),by=Tag]
```

P.S. I am not displaying results as you did not `set.seed` in your example and thus the results will not match yours.

Answer (score 0):

Note, I'm also working on marking recapture data, so I'm posting some other ways much longer, but allows to check for duration between mark and recapture.

```
set.seed(10)
tlran=c(rnorm(5,mean=50,sd=5),rnorm(5,mean=200,sd=5), rnorm(5,mean=400,sd=10))
TaggingData=as.data.frame(trunc(tlran,0))
names(TaggingData)="TL"
TaggingData$Tag=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,7,3,4,8,1,9,10,3)
TaggingData$Date=c("01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2015","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2016","01.01.2017","01.01.2017","01.01.2017","01.01.2017","01.01.2017")


TaggingData$Date <- as.Date(strptime(TaggingData$Date,format="%d.%m.%Y"))
require(dplyr)
require(plyr)
growth<-plyr::join(
        group_by(TaggingData,Tag)%>%
            slice(which.min(Date))%>%
            summarize(             
                capture=min(Date),
                TL1=min(TL)), 
       group_by(TaggingData,Tag)%>%
              slice(which.max(Date))%>%
              summarize(             
                     lastcapture=max(Date),
                     TL2=max(TL))
         )%>%
    mutate(
        duration_year=as.numeric(difftime(lastcapture,capture,units="days")/365),
        growth=TL2-TL1)%>%
    mutate(yearly_growth=growth/duration_year)%>%
    arrange(Tag)
```

So in the end my table looks like :

```
   Tag    capture TL1 lastcapture TL2 duration growth yearly_growth
1    1 2015-01-01  50  2017-01-01 407 731 days    357   0.001338006
2    2 2015-01-01  49  2015-01-01  49   0 days      0           NaN
3    3 2015-01-01  43  2017-01-01 407 731 days    364   0.001364241
4    4 2015-01-01  47  2016-01-01 198 365 days    151   0.001133421
5    5 2015-01-01  51  2015-01-01  51   0 days      0           NaN
6    6 2016-01-01 201  2016-01-01 201   0 days      0           NaN
7    7 2016-01-01 198  2016-01-01 198   0 days      0           NaN
8    8 2017-01-01 411  2017-01-01 411   0 days      0           NaN
9    9 2017-01-01 397  2017-01-01 397   0 days      0           NaN
10  10 2017-01-01 409  2017-01-01 409   0 days      0           NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
dcast(Recap, Tag  ~ Date, value.var = c("TL"))
```

gives the following, not growth but might be usefull in case of marking campains with fixed dates

```
    Tag 2015-01-01 2016-01-01 2017-01-01
 1:   1         50        193        407
 2:   2         49         NA         NA
 3:   3         43        191        407
 4:   4         47        198         NA
 5:   5         51         NA         NA
 6:   6         NA        201         NA
 7:   7         NA        198         NA
 8:   8         NA         NA        411
 9:   9         NA         NA        397
10:  10         NA         NA        409
```